# Shopware 6 plugin: How to Remove and Migrate boolean config to multi-select config

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I have a Shopware 6 plugin that currently uses a boolean config `reviewSkipModeration` value that automatically publishes any reviews submitted through the plugin:

`config.xml`

```xml
<input-field type="bool">
  <name>reviewSkipModeration</name>
  <label>Accept reviews automatically</label>
  <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
</input-field>
```

The current version of the plugin is 1.7.2. In the new version 1.7.3, I want to remove `reviewSkipModeration` boolean config and add a new `autoPublishStars` multi-select config :

`config.xml`

```xml
        <input-field type="single-select">
            <name>autoPublishStars</name>
            <label>Auto Publish review with stars</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Sterne vorausgewählt</label>
            <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
            <options>
                <option>
                    <id>None</id>
                    <name>None</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">None</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>0</id>
                    <name>0 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">0 Stars</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>1 Star</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">1 Stern</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <name>2 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">2 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <name>3 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">3 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <name>4 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">4 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <name>5 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">5 Sterne</name>
                </option>
            </options>
        </input-field>
```

The current logic for this is implemented in a controller. As I want to remove `if (!$this->config->getReviewSkipModeration()) {...}` for the new version what changes should be done in the controller? :

```php
            $commentStatus = true;
            
            if($reviewPoints < $this->config->getAutoPublishStars()){
                $commentStatus = !$commentStatus;
            }
            
            if (!$this->config->getReviewSkipModeration()) {
                $commentStatus = false;
            }

            $create = [
                'productId' => $sArticleId,
                'customerId' => $customer->getCustomerId(),
                'salesChannelId' => $salesChannelContext->getSalesChannel()->getId(),
                'languageId' => $salesChannelContext->getContext()->getLanguageId(),
                'externalUser' => $this->anonymizeName($isAnon, $customer),
                'externalEmail' => $orderNumberAsEmail,
                'title' => $commentHeadline,
                'content' => $commentContent,
                'points' => $reviewPoints,
                'status' => $commentStatus,
            ];
```

I want to migrate boolean config functionality to the new version in a way **to avoid changing the default behavior for existing users during an update** to a multi-select config with the following options. How can I use the "None" from config.xml to the controller? Can I access the "None" option the same way as "0" is accessible in the controller?:

- None
- 0 Stars
- 1 Star
- 2 Stars
- 3 Stars
- 4 Stars
- 5 Stars

In my update method, how can I migrate the data properly so:

- false maps to None
- true maps to 0 Stars

My update function of the plugin looks like:

```php
    public function update(UpdateContext $context): void {
        parent::update($context);
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to handle the mapping. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you should start by changing your update method you can check if the old bool config is true or false then map it to the corresponding new multi-select config

```
public function update(UpdateContext $context): void
{
    parent::update($context);

    $previousConfigVal = $this->config->getReviewSkipModeration();
    $newConfigVal = $previousConfigVal ? 0 : 'None';
 
    $this->config->setAutoPublishStars($newConfigVal);
}
```

and after that you can use a simple [switch][1] or [match][2] if you're using PHP 8 , for different options

```
$autoPublishStars = $this->config->getAutoPublishStars();
switch ($autoPublishStars) {
    case 'None':
        $commentStatus = false;
        break;
    case '0':
        $commentStatus = false;
        break;
    case '1':
        $commentStatus = ($reviewPoints >= 1);
        break;
    case '2':
        $commentStatus = ($reviewPoints >= 2);
        break;
    case '3':
        $commentStatus = ($reviewPoints >= 3);
        break;
    case '4':
        $commentStatus = ($reviewPoints >= 4);
        break;
    case '5':
        $commentStatus = ($reviewPoints >= 5);
        break;
    default:
        $commentStatus = true;
 }
```

I think this might really work for you if it didn't we can brainstorm a solution together
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php
[2]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php

Comment: Secondly, How can I access `$this->config` in my plugin php file?

Comment: what happens when this is run and the setting isn't there anymore?
`$previousConfigVal  = $configService->getBool('TanmarNgProductReviews.config.reviewSkipModeration');` Because we intend to remove it completely.